# Product ID is not being stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, fetch

can anyone help? my code doesn't seem to store the value of product id here in my code have a look I am also getting the ID from another table

```
    <?php
include("Connection.php");
$dTime = time();
$myValue = $_REQUEST['dValue'];
echo "<p>
The time is: {$dTime}<br/>
The choice is {$myValue}
</p>
";



$sql = "Select ID from product where NAME = '$myValue'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    $pid=$row["PRODUCT_ID"];



$sql2 = "INSERT INTO  `starbucks`.`order_details` (
`ID` ,
`ORDER_ID` ,
`PRODUCT_ID` ,
`QTY`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '',  '$pid',  '1'
)";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
?>
```

updated the code

Comment: I hope you're not coding anything for starbucks :D

Comment: Are you seeing the ID on the screen after the page is run?

Comment: I am not seeing any ID, and no I am not coding for starbucks, It's a copy cat of starbucks lol . for my project

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $row["ID"]
```

instead of:

```
$id = $row;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your original code there is no error handling,you should do something like this:

```
$sql = "Select ID from product where NAME = '$myValue'";
if ($sql) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $pid = $row["PRODUCT_ID"];



    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO  `starbucks`.`order_details` (
    `ID` ,
    `ORDER_ID` ,
    `PRODUCT_ID` ,
    `QTY`
    )
    VALUES (
    NULL ,  '',  '$pid',  '1'
    )";

    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    if (!$result2) {
        echo mysql_error();
        break;
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

And see what error you get.

Comment: I have another variable, and it's not the Primary key

Comment: Yup my bad as I saw it now, by presumably your `starbucks.id` is auto-increment so you shouldn't pas NULL, just drop the id from fields list and values from insert query.

Comment: what is undefined variable ? the ID field of Starbucks or the $row['id'] ?

Comment: my error is "Notice: Undefined variable: pid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Self Exercise\proj\sampleDiv.php "

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect array value for `$id` instead of the array's `ID` key:

```
$id = $row;

// Should be
$id = $row['ID'];
```